# print the line with a pattern as it is and find the difference between patterns from two files

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have two files: -

(Note, group name will always have a : at the end)

File1

```
Group1:
user1
user2
Group2:
User1
User2
User3
```

File 2

```
Group1:
user1
Group2:
User1
User2
User3
User4
```

Group names and user names are not static and can change. I want to be able to print additions from each group in the one output file and deletions from each group in the another output file. The output files should look like the following: -

addoutput file

```
Group1:
Group2:
User4
```

deleteoutput file

```
Group1:
User2
Group2:
```

Basically, file 1 is the list of users available in group 1 and group 2 previously and file 2 is the list of users that were added or removed from group1 and group 2 when the group membership were audited last.

Addition output file should show any members that are added to either group along with the group name and deletion output file should show any members that are deleted from the groups along with the group names.

Can this be done by sed or awk?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking, I'd suggest you use `awk`.  If you have `comm` then the task would be quite straightforward.  Using `comm`, you could proceed as follows:

(1) use `awk` to convert the files so that each line has the form:

```
groupname: username
```

(2) sort the two files and use `comm -23 FILE1 FILE2` to compute FILE1 - FILE2 (and similarly for the other way around)

3) use `awk` to revert to the desired format.

Comment: Great suggestion. I tried it and it helped me find the group with changes and all its members instead of the the diff. But thank you for guiding me into the right direction.